# C++ STL map - conditional insert

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I'm looking for an efficient way to do a conditional insert. Ideally, I'd like a template function that would work on any map. I want something like this:

```
std::map<int, std::string> MyMap;
if(MyMap.ConditionalInsert(3, "Hello"))
{ // there was no element 3, one has been added with value "Hello"
}
else
{ // there was already an element 3 in the map, it's unchanged
}
```

I can't easily use `operator[]` because there's no easy way to tell if it created an element or not. I can use `count` for the test, but then I have to search the map twice if we do an insert. I guess something with `find` would be best, but it always seems to come out warty and awkward.

Is there a really good way to do this?

Comment: would it work just like you described for the multi- variants as well?

Comment: So basically you want an iterator that will point to a preexisting element if it exists already, or point to an empty spot that you can fill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What problem do you see with this:

```
auto ret = MyMap.insert(std::make_pair(3, "Hello"));

if( ret.second)
{ 
    //the value is inserted
}
else
{
    //no value is inserted
}
```

The return value indicates whether the value is already present or not. If it is not present, the value will be inserted, else no value will be inserted.

Taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/):

> ... returns a pair, with its member pair::first set to an iterator pointing to either the newly inserted element or to the element that already had its same value in the map. **The pair::second element in the pair is set to true if a new element was inserted or false if an element with the same value existed.**

Comment: Should be `ret.second`, not `ret->second`.

Comment: @DerekLedbetter: Power failure and internet was down, so couldn't respond to your comment. I corrected it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

### Do not overwrite previous values, what to use?

[`std::map<T1,T2>::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/) already does this check for you, if there already is an entry with the specified key the insert will be aborted.

```
  std::map<int, std::string> m;

  m.insert (std::make_pair (3, "hello world"));
  m.insert (std::make_pair (3, "world hello"));

  std::cerr << m[3] << std::endl;
```

output:

```
  hello world
```

---

### Was the new value inserted?

`std::map<T1,T2>::insert` returns a `std::pair<std::map<T1,T2>::iterator, bool>`, the 2nd value (`pair.second`) will act as a flag saying if the key/value pair was inserted or not.

```
if ret.second ==  true: value was inserted
if ret.second == false: the key has already been set
```

example snippet:

```
  std::cerr << m.insert (std::make_pair (1,1)).second << std::endl;
  std::cerr << m.insert (std::make_pair (1,2)).second << std::endl;
```

output

```
  1
  0
```

Comment: Why using `std::cerr`? Why not `std::cout`?

Comment: `std::cerr` is an unbuffered stream normally used for debug and diagnostics. Since providing a sample snippet can fall under either of does two I most often make my snippets write to `std::cerr` instead off std::cout. Read more about stderr, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29).

Comment: Alright. If that is the point, then I think `std::clog` makes more sense for *debug and diagnostics*.

Comment: On *nix debug/diagnostic/info messages are usually/always sent to stderr, this is what I grew up with and what I will continue doing, thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1):

The `insert` function already does what you want.

```
std::pair<std::map<int, std::string>::iterator, bool>
    insertionResult = MyMap.insert(std::make_pair(3, "Hello"));

if(insertionResult.second)
{ // there was no element 3, one has been added with value "Hello"
}
else
{ // there was already an element 3 in the map, it's unchanged
}
```

The first element of the pair gives the location of the element with the key, whether it's old or new.